# Sub-classed UICollectionViewCell not updating image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uicollectionview

I am trying to make a collection view show multiple selections by adding a badge in each cell view. It sets the initial (unselected) image correctly, but the view is never updated to the selected version. I've tried setting it manually, so I know the selected image works and is visible in the cell. The NSLog shows 'selected' is toggling as expected and breakpoints show that the appropriate assignment to the image is being executed. Excuse the indention, SO won't play nicely and it's after midnight.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SMListCollectionViewCell *cell = (SMListCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if ( !indexPath.row )
{
    cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Add"];
    cell.label.text = @"Create New";
    cell.imageBadge.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
    cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[listManager.myLists[indexPath.row-1] valueForKey:keyDetailImage]];
    cell.label.text = [listManager.myLists[indexPath.row-1] valueForKey:keyName];
    cell.imageBadge.hidden = !self.editing;
    NSLog(@"selected is %d",cell.selected);
    if ( cell.selected )
    {
        cell.imageBadge.image = self.badgeSelected;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageBadge.image = self.badgeUnselected;
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: it's incredibly difficult to do this well.  don't forget **the cell is changing and being redrawn all the time**.  you have to "select" something ***in your data***.  so if you have an array of "cars", say 10 of them, and "3" is selected.  you have to have a field in cars, and *in number three, you have to set that Cars as 'selected'*.  then you have to use that quality when you draw the cells in `tableView#cellForRowAt`

Comment: @JoeBlow Let me know what you think about the approach I've proposed in _answers_ below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Woah!** Checking for a `cell`'s `selected` state from within `cellForAtIndexPath:` is guaranteed to *not* work.

Since you have already created a custom cell subclass `SMListCollectionViewCell`, you need to override its `selected` setter & toggle the image to be shown on cell from in there.

Since the `imageBadge` attribute is already exposed in `SMListCollectionViewCell.h`, a quick snippet of only `.m` would look like:

```
// SMListCollectionViewCell.m

#import "SMListCollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation SMListCollectionViewCell

... 

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected{
    [super setSelected:selected];

    if (selected){
        cell.imageBadge.image = self.badgeSelected;
    }
    else {
        cell.imageBadge.image = self.badgeUnselected;
    }
}

@end
```

This will handle toggling of images depending on cell selection state.

Additionally, `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` will now morph to:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SMListCollectionViewCell *cell = (SMListCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!indexPath.row){

        cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Add"];
        cell.label.text = @"Create New";
        cell.imageBadge.hidden = YES;
    }
    else {

        cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[listManager.myLists[indexPath.row-1] valueForKey:keyDetailImage]];
        cell.label.text = [listManager.myLists[indexPath.row-1] valueForKey:keyName];
        cell.imageBadge.hidden = !self.editing;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @josh-caswell thanks for edit but I thought emojis are fun! :) 
hahaha

Comment: We don't really go in for them around here. Good answer, though.

Comment: Glad you liked it. 

Comment: Thank you! Copy'n'pasted your answer and it works perfectly - apart from needing to tweak the references to 'cell' and 'self' in setSelected, which I've edited in.